# Force UK Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Date Picker script where a user can select a date. The script then adds 5 working days to the date to give the user their anticipated delivery date. The issue that I am having is where some users have their browser input set to English(US) it is reversing the date.

Below is the small bit of code that gets the date then adds the 5 working days to the date. The date is then outputted into the text field "deliveryDate"

Is there a way that I can force the output in "deliveryDate" to be in UK format?

```
<script src="custom/deliveryDate/deliveryDate.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

myVal=WorkDayAdd(5);

PFSF_Find("FIELD_" + FieldIDs["deliveryDate"]).value=myVal;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great library for working with dates (formatting included) - moment.js. You can create a custom date format or use one provided by the localization module.

You can check it here: https://momentjs.com/